# How can i call theme colour in constructor

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

```
var boxDecoration = BoxDecoration(
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
  color: Colors.grey.shade300,
  
  boxShadow: [
    BoxShadow(
        blurRadius: 15,
        offset: Offset(4, 4),
        color: Colors.grey.shade500,
        spreadRadius: 1),
    BoxShadow(
        blurRadius: 15,
        offset: Offset(-4, -4),
        color: Colors.white,
        spreadRadius: 1)
  ],
);
```

This is my constructor for the container, I want to change its color according to the system theme. Like different colors for the dark and light themes.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will prefer using method in this case,

```dart
BoxDecoration boxDecoration(BuildContext context) => BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
        color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
        boxShadow: [...],
      );
```

And use it like `decoration: boxDecoration(context),`

Comment: i want to use these colors       theme: ThemeData.light().copyWith(
          primaryColor: Colors.grey.shade300,
          accentColor: Colors.grey.shade500,
          canvasColor: Colors.white,
        ),

Comment: you need to place it under `MaterialApp`, you can check [this](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/design/themes)